# GeoServer and local PostgreSQL database without Internet

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, pgadmin-3

simple question: can I work on GeoServer and local PostgreSQL database on my PC without need for Internet connection ?

would I be able to connect GeoServer to the database and create layers ? also would I be able to use pgAdmin and postGIS full usage ?

Comment: just use localhost:port number example h:ttp://localhost:8088/geoserver/web/ your postgres database will be localhost: different port number localhost:5432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. PostgreSQL is set up to only accept local connections, and GeoServer is set up to use the loopback address i.e. 127.0.0.1 on port 8080.

So you can run the standard installers and everything should just work when you type:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

You'll need to set up GeoServer to see your PostgreSQL database, but that's standard stuff covered in the tutorials, and should use the address:

```
localhost:5432
```